# Ansible transform mixed list structure to a uniform structure

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

In Ansible, if I have a list variable with the following mixed structure:

```
input_items:
    - mainkey: 'main.value.1'
      subkey: 'subvalue_1.1'

    - mainkey: 'main.value.2'
        group:
            - subkey: 'subvalue_2.1'
            - subkey: 'subvalue_2.2'
```

Is there a way to transform it to a flat structure like this:

```
transformed:
    - mainkey: 'main.value.1'
      subkey: 'subvalue_1.1'

    - mainkey: 'main.value.2'
      subkey: 'subvalue_2.1'

    - mainkey: 'main.value.2'
      subkey: 'subvalue_2.2'
```

The idea being to allow a more compact structure to define the list, then transform it to a flat structure that is simple to feed in to a module using `with_items`.

I've exhausted every shape of loop, include, set_fact and jinja filter I can muster but I'm sure there must be a way.

Comment: Highly unlikely this will be solvable inside Ansible. You should look into creating a custom filter plugin. http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/developing_plugins.html#filter-plugins

Answer (score 1):

As per udondan's suggestion I've created a filter plugin to do just this. [Here is a gist with the full python code and example data](https://gist.github.com/DominicBarnard/d7692b2d04837217465b). 
I've also [suggested it to the ansible google group for inclusion into core](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ansible-devel/GKUfI3oymPY). You can comment there if you'd like to see it in core.